# Node Js Express Js form resubmission error

Tags: node.js, forms, express, handlebars.js, backend

How to prevent form resubmission on page refresh or back button in express js ? On refresh I want the same page to be reloaded and on back button the previous state of the page .

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want to keep the data on the form the same upon refresh?

If you want it to be saved upon refresh you need to save the data the user inputs somewhere.

Either **locally** in local storage or on the **server**.

If you choose local storage:  On every refresh you check local storage to see if data is already there and if so you populate the form with that data.

If you choose to store the un-submitted data on the server you should be maintaining a session with the server.  You can use a cookie here and node has a few good options/ways to do this.

Storing what page the user is on can also be stored in either location.

If you have the option to choose either local or remote - I'd go with local storage.